# How to find alphabet, number in one string then put newline in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have trouble to make this. I don't know maybe I am bad at this, I can't imagine how the code works.
I have string file :

```
My mama told me that I am: a. must be an engineer; but b. I want to be a Doctor.
```

The Output is:

```
My mama told me that I am: 
a. must be an engineer; but 
b. I want to be a Doctor.
```

The second string is :

```
(1) My mama told me that I am must be an engineer; but (2) I want to be a Doctor: a. I am must learn Biology. b. That's my dream. c. I can help people.
```

The output is:

```
(1) My mama told me that I am must be an engineer; but 
(2) I want to be a Doctor: 
    a. I am must learn Biology. 
    b. That's my dream. 
    c. I can help people.
```

I tried using `.find` then put "\n", but I can't find a way to give "\n" in the middle of the string. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and include the minimal reproducible example for us to help you.

Comment: The output that you have written,is this the output you want or the output that your program is showing?

Comment: Also,if you are reading this content through a file,there is a function 'f.readline()',that reads one line at a time.

Comment: I want the output showing like that sir. Hmm so I use 'f.readlines()' to reads the line and I put '\n' there?

Answer (score 0):

While SO isn't a coding service, I'll give you a hint for your first string that you can easily expand for the second:

```
s = "My mama told me that I am: a. must be an engineer; but b. I want to be a Doctor."

import re

patterns = re.findall(" [a-z]\. ", s)

i = 0
new_s = ""
for item in patterns:
    j = s.index(item)
    if item == patterns[-1]:
        new_s += s[i:j].strip() + "\n" + s[j: ].strip()
    else:
        new_s += s[i:j].strip() + "\n"
        i = j

print(new_s)
```